# Pyodbc can never connect locally, but can connect remotely

Tags: python, sql-server

```
    import pyodbc

server = 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx'
database = 'Stackoverflow'
username = 'sa'
password = 'azeqsd789456'
connection_string = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'

try:
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM testforms")
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

So this query above is working fine, when I'm using it from my computer, to connect to a database remotely. It works perfectly fine. but then, if I bring that same code to the machine where the DB is, the connection keeps failing:

> Failed to connect to the database. Error: (pyodbc.OperationalError)
> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL
> Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
> [xFFFFFFFF].  (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 11 for SQL Serve r]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error
> has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is
> not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
> SQL Server is configured  to allow remote connections. For more
> information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1)')**

I have tried to use as server the following:

- localhost
- (local),1433
- (local)
- The actual instance name without SQLEXPRESS (and with)
- The same IP I'm using for remote access

Nothing worked (these things work in `SQL Management studio` just fine but just not when connecting with python). I also tried to use `pymmsql`

Also, not sure if this is of any importance:
I'm using a similar code to the above to connect, and it's returning that the **data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (sqldriverconnect)**

which I know for a fact is not true, because that same `ODBC` is being printed when I call `pyodbc.drivers()`.

I went through every possible solution I came across on Stackoverflow, but none of them seemed to work for both issues.

Comment: what error do you get when you use localhost on the *database server*?

Comment: Hi, the error is under the code.

Comment: no, that's error you get when you use xxx.xx.xx.xx on the database server

Comment: No, I'm getting the same error, regardless to what I'm using. (local), localhost, IP address, etc.

Comment: Actually, I just switched to ODBC 18, and the error still say ODBC 11? how come,

Comment: Sounds like you're editing one file and running another?

Answer (score 2):

If you can connect to 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx' from your local machine, it means that one of two things:

1. there's something listening to port 1433, meaning you should be able to access same server when you do localhost on server xxx.xx.xx.xxx. OR,
2. there might be some port-forwarding going on, in which case the real server isn't listening on 1433. Check the sql configuration on the xxx.xx.xx.xxx to see the real port.

You can also run following on the server:

```sql
declare @x table (logdate datetime, processinfo sysname, text nvarchar(max))

insert into @x
exec xp_readerrorlog 

select *
from @x
where text like '%server is listening on%'
```

It should list the ports the server is listening on

Comment: I figured it out, after you said you might be editing another file...

Apparently and for whatever reason, I had to save each time I made any change to the code in VS, otherwise recompiling it wouldn't take the new changes into consideration.

There was no issue with the code above.

Thanks!